# Is it possible to query the enable/disable status of a window with Microsoft JScript?

Tags: javascript, wmi

Is it possible to query the enable/disable status of a window with Microsoft JScript?

I have this working code

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd,LPARAM lParam)
{
   wchar_t text[80];
   if ( ::GetWindowText( hwnd, text, 80 ) ) {
      if ( std::wstring(text).find(L"MyApp") != std::wstring::npos ) {
         std::wcout << ::IsWindowEnabled( hwnd ) << L"\t" << text << L"\n";
      }
   }
   return TRUE;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
   while(true){
      ::EnumWindows( EnumWindowsProc, 0 );
      ::Sleep(1000);
   }
    return 0;
}
```

and I would like to convert it into a JScript script (and running it through `cscript.exe`).

Maybe is there a way of doing it with WMI?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither JScript/WSH nor WMI have this functionality (WSH's GUI interaction capabilities are limited to [`SendKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83.aspx) and [`AppActivate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek.aspx), and WMI doesn't work with GUI at all).

However, if you definitely prefer scripts to compiled code and don't mind using third-party components or scripting environments other than WSH, you can do this.

For example, in an [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) script, you can check the enabled/disabled state of a window using the [`WinGetState`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinGetState.htm) function. You can also call this function from JScript through the AutoIt ActiveX/COM control:

```
// Note: this code is untested
var oAutoIt = new ActiveXObject("AutoItX3.Control");
var state = oAutoIt.WinGetState("MyApp");
var isEnabled = state & 4;
```